# Parse.initialize crashes when opening

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I've been trying to work with Parse for a while and I'm having a simple problem. I believe I am missing something with syntax but I could be wrong.

Every time I run the line,

```
Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID", "CLIENT_ID");
```

I may have those in the wrong order. But on my system they are correct. 
The application opens then closes immediately. When I moved the code, it crashes on that window.

What am I missing?

Here is my pointApp.java file:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;


public class pointApp extends Application {
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.w("CONTENT:","OPENING...");
        try {
            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
            Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID", "CLIENT_ID");
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Log.v("Error:", "Unable to connect");
        }
    }
}
```

On my activity page, launch.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;


public class launch extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //here check if the gps is on.
        setContentView(R.layout.gps_check);


        /*THIS SHOULD REMOVE BECASE THEY SHOULDNT BE ABLE TO SKIP THE GPS SCREEN*/
        Button continue_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_btn);
        continue_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.start"));
            }
        });
        /*END OF CODE THAT GETS  REMOVE */
    }

}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.-.point">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".pointApp">
    <activity
        android:name=".launch"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".start"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.start"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".login"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.login"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".signup"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.signup"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".friends_list"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.friends_list"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".add_friend"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.add_friend"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".point"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.point"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to substitute in your app id and client id. It's on the Parse dashboard.

Comment: I know that. I removed it for this post.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps your jar file is broken.
please check your lib jar files.
I saw such error in my project.
When I exchange lib jar files, the error disappeared.
Please try this way.